# Lyapunov matrix equation theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, stability-theory

I know the following Lyapunov's theorem:

For any symmetric positive definite matrix $Q$, the following are equivalent

1- The matrix equation $A^T X + X A = -Q $ has a unique solution $X$ that is symmetric and positive definite.

2- Matrix $A$ is Hurwitz, i.e. all of its eigenvalues have strictly negative real parts.

---

My question is, can I propose this following theorem:

If matrix $A$ is not Hurwitz, then $A^T X + X A = -I $ does not have a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: What is missing is the positive definiteness of $X$

Answer (score 3):

No. A counterexample:
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
-2&0\\
0&1\\
\end{array}\right)
\qquad
X=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
\frac14&0\\
0&-\frac12\\
\end{array}\right).
$$